# UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey returning wrong ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I want to add Transition animation from ViewController1 to ViewController2. Following picture showing BaseTabBarController and TableViewController. BaseTabBarController has its over .h and .m files named (BaseTabBarController); If i will add any view in base tab bar then it will be added in TableViewController. I am pushing a third ViewController from TableViewController. So in below code, **fromVC** should be TableViewController but it contains BaseTabBarViewController. I can’t able to get any idea what’s going on here? Please suggest any solution so that i can move forward. I will be thankful to all of you.
[image]

```
    -(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController <ZoomTransitionProtocol> * fromVC = (id)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController <ZoomTransitionProtocol> *toVC = (id)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView * containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIView * fromView = [fromVC view];
    UIView * toView = [toVC view];

    [containerView addSubview:toView];

    UIView * zoomFromView = [fromVC viewForZoomTransition];
    UIView * zoomToView = [toVC viewForZoomTransition];

//Code is continuing…

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue and its resolved and working perfectly.

**Solution:**
Look into following screenshot:
[image]

You will notice that, firstly, **Navigation Controller** is places and then ViewController; Afterwards, a **TabBarController** will come; TabBarController's first item is TableViewController;
When we push any view controller from any of the tabBar item, it will push because we have root navigation controller; So no need to add separate navigation controllers for each and every tab.

But **UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey** will return BaseTabBar classes. So for resolve the issue, i just added a new **Navigation Controller** for tabBar item. Now it will return correct **FromViewCotroller**. 
Following is the correct screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. But I get `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setThing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc86b5ab1e0'` because I'm trying to pass some data to the modal view - Did you have to setup a Controller for the new Navigation Controller?

Comment: @GabrielMSharp I just added a Navigation Controller; If you need to pass some parameters then you need to do it like in story board.